# Django rest with djoser returns detail:invalid token on first login

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, djoser

I am using Django rest with Djoser package and in local everything works fine.

I login with username and password to `token/login/` and get token in response, but on heroku I get `details:invalid token` response, which means I cannot even get a token.

Some settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 1000,
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}
```

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'sales',
    'inventory',
    'graphene_django',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_pivot',
    'drf_spectacular',
    'django_extensions',
    'djoser',
]
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view()), ## left from Session authentication

    path('', include('sales.urls')),
    path('inventory/', include('inventory.urls')),
    path('graphql', csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True))),

    path('',  include('djoser.urls')),
    path('',  include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),

    # swagger paths
    path('api/schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='schema'),
    path('api/schema/swagger-ui/',
         SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='schema'), name='swagger-ui'),

]
```

on the frontend:

```
axios.defaults.headers["Authorization"] = `Token ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`;
```

What could be the wrong?

Comment: I'm a djoser maintainer, I have an app with djoser on heroku and after a brief look I have no idea why that happens to you. Are you sure your credentials are right? Did you run all the migrations?

Comment: hello, finally, the issue was on frontend. With the axios line I have essentially sent `Authorization: Token null` header instead of `Authorization: null`. Thats why I would get response `invalid token`. If that's djoser response maybe make something like `invalid token null`, `token is null` or something similar. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue was on frontend.

Line

```
axios.defaults.headers["Authorization"] = `Token ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`;
```

sends a request header `Authorization: Token null` which backend interprets as invalid token. Better header would be `Authorization: null` which works.

So something like this:

```
axios.defaults.headers["Authorization"] = token ? `Token ${token} : null`
```

Personally I have used interceptor:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  config.headers.Authorization = token ? `Token ${token}` : null;
  return config;
});
```